# Mixture models vs marginal distributions

Tags: statistics, marginal-distribution

Maybe I'm not understanding these concepts correctly, but it seems like the idea of a mixture model seems to be superfluous, since we can express any mixture of random variables as a multivariate distribution, and marginalize it to get the exact same thing as the mixture.

I'm using the definitions below:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution

In particular, if we toss two different coins, one 90% of the time and another 10% of the time, where the first is a fair coin and the second is heads 70%, is this not modeled by a multivariate distribution, the two variables being coin type and the other being Heads/Tails in this way:

|  | H | T |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Coin 1 | .45 | .45 |
| Coin 2 | .07 | .03 |

And you can just take the marginal distribution for H-T from there?

Comment: A typical finite mixture model looks like $f = \pi_1 f_1 + \cdots + \pi_k f_k$ where $f_1, \dots, f_k$ are densities or probability mass functions and $\pi_1, \dots, \pi_k$ are the mixing proportions.

Comment: @Aruralreader So in this case we have $\pi_1$=.9 and $\pi_2$=.1 with the two rows representing $f_1$ and $f_2$ respectively. And $f$ turns out to coincide with $p_X(x)$, where $X$ is the variable for heads or tails. Could you elaborate on what your point is here?

Comment: You seemed to be confused between the concepts of marginal distributions and mixture models. Lots of apparent similarities in a simple case like this where you're given a table of total probabilities. Mixture models extend to the case where you simply have measurements and you don't know $\pi_1, \dots, \pi_k$ or even the parameters of the $f$s for that matter. Best of luck in your studies!

Answer (score 1):

In your case you do not need this. If you know the weights for each category and the distriution of each category, you can trivially calculate the total distribution. But what if you do not know how fair your two coins are? This is what a model is. We do not know some parameters, and we try to find these parameters from observations.

Comment: But couldn't the parameters be just as well expressed as part of this total distribution?

Comment: Yes, you *could* do that, depending on the model. As I said, there is no real benefit to it, as it would be doing the same thing in a complicated way.
But the thing is: A model is usually about fitting an observed behaviour. Your distribution tells us nothing about how you’d arrive at these parameters, it just gives us a slightly more complicated way of writing down the model.

Comment: Makes sense. I could see that if you decided to avoid mentioning anything about mixture models at all, if your knowledge strongly suggests a "mixed process" you'd end up writing something like $p(x) = \pi_1 p(x|1) + \pi_2 p(x|2)$ anyways, and put constraints on the parameters to have exactly what you said: a more complicated way of writing down the model.

Comment: An example. A baseball fanatic hands you a list of 10,000 measurements of batters' exit velocities, typically 10-110 mph, telling you he's collected it from the pros, the minors, college level, and little league. No indication which group a velocity comes from, but you're asked estimate how many from each. How do you write down the distribution?